# Is there a way to bypass a router login screen?

Tags: javascript, html, ip

I was challanged recently to "hack" into my router, by that I mean already having connected to the internet, but hack into the local IP. So basically bypass the login screen. The router is a Livebox. I already have tried looking at the source code but the password seems to be hidden.

[Here's a picture of the login screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DMmT.png)

If you can help than thank you very much.

Oh by the way, here's the source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<script language="JavaScript">
var remote_clt=0;
var sipp_proxy_flag=1;
var pcp_gui_enable=1;
var nat_from_upnp=1;
var my_auto_detect_fxo=0;
var my_isolate_wlan=1;
var X02_pf=1;
var adsl_para_page=0;
var my_ddns=1;
var my_wlan_mac=0;
var my_snmp=0;
var my_dialup=0;
var my_printer=0;
var my_bridge=0;
var my_8021x=0;
var my_tiny=0;
var my_vpn=0;
var my_upnp=1;
var my_usb=1;
var my_usb_storage=1;
var my_usb_printer=1;
var operation_func=10;
var my_wps=1;
var my_wcn=1;
var my_ralink_ver=0;
var feature_func=1;
var product_code=1024020;
var my_file_share=1;
var my_umts=0;
var vlan_func_enable=1;
var vlan_ip="";
var vlan_mask="";
var my_qos=2;
var my_isdn=0;
var my_voip=1;
var FXS_Num=8;
var my_voip_h323=0;
var my_voip_sip=1;
var ipsec_func=0;
var pptp_func=0;
var br_dhcpd_func=0;
var iptv_func=0;
var static_rt_func=0;
var my_upnpIgd=1;
var my_upnpAv=1;
var PM="DSL Router";
var BACKUP_LOG_NAME="dsl_log.log";
var BACKUP_CONFIG_NAME="config_dsl.bin";
var resetButton=0;
var hasUpgrade=0;
var ftpcRun=0;
var dhcpd_fixip_func=1;
var vendor_code=6;
var my_http_redir=0;
var arcor_umtsPin=0;
var my_ncidd=0;
var ipv6_service=1;
var ipv6_enable=1;
var hyper_link="<a href='http://www.arcadyan.com' target='_blank'>";
var urlname="www.arcadyan.com";
var product_name="Arcadyan ARV7519";
var vendor_name="DSL-EasyBox";
var company="Arcadyan Inc.";
var mouseover="'#FF6600'";
var mouseout="'#FFFFFF'";
var wizardbg="'#FFFFFF'";
var menu_link="<td height='0' align='left' bgColor='#FFFFFF' valign='middle'>";
var vendor_no=2;
var helplink="<p></p>";
var logo_fn="logo.gif";
var help_hyper_link="<a href='http://www.arcadyan.com/802' target='_blank'>";
var help_urlname="www.arcadyan.com/802";
var fw_hyper_link="<a href='http://www.arcadyan.com' target='_blank'>";
var fw_urlname="www.arcadyan.com";
var product_pic_fn="product_zz.gif";

var firmware_ver='00.96.806B';

if (parent.location.href != window.location.href)
parent.location.href = window.location.href;

function evaltF() {
    document.tF.submit();
}

function kDown(e)
{
    var key = 0 ;
    if(window.event)  key = window.event.keyCode;
    else if(e)        key = e.which ;

    if(key==13) document.tF.submit();
    //if (navigator.appName =='Netscape'&&(e.which ==3||e.which ==2|| e.which ==13))
    //  document.tF.submit();
    //else if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' &&(event.keyCode == 13))
    //  document.tF.submit();
}

document.onkeypress=kDown;
if (document.layers) window.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);
//window.onkeypress=kDown;
function init()
{
var f=document.tF;
f.pws.focus();
if(remote_clt==1)
f.user.readOnly=false;
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contener.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="subcontener.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="array.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hardware.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="button.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lbpopup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="progressbar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="97%" height="83">
    <tr height="55">
        <form ACTION="/cgi-bin/changef.exe" method="post" name="tFF">
        <input type="hidden" name="language_flag" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="menupage" value="/login.stm">
        <td class="header" width="313"><div id="header"><h4>livebox</h4></div></td>
        <td class="style1">
        <img src="/images/language_en_gray.gif" width="70" height="29" border="0">&nbsp;
        <input type="image" src="/images/language_es.gif" width="70" height="29" border="0">
        </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class= bgstripe height="28" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form action="/cgi-bin/login.exe" method="post" name="tF">
<div id="menu" style="margin-left: 40%; margin-top: 60px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="topleft"></td>
            <td class="top"></td>
            <td class="topright"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left"></td>
            <td>
                <div class="info_accueil">
                    <table class="info_accueil">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="info_pref"><img src="images/preferencesbutton.gif">Authentication</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="info_label">Login:</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="info_field"><input type="text" name="user" value="admin" class="login" readonly></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="info_label">Password:</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="info_field"><input type="password" maxlength="12" size="32" name="pws" class="password"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="info_statusnok">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sepleftbig"></td>
            <td class="sepactbig">
                Click here to validate <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="evaltF(); return false;" class="button60l"><img src="images/nextbutton.gif" border="0"></a></td>
            <td class="right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bottomleft"></td>
            <td class="bottom"></td>
            <td class="bottomright"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan=3></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=3></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
<br><br><br>
<p>
    <style type="text/css">
    p { text-align:center;
        font-size:20;
        color: #FF6600;
    }
    a {
        color: #FF6600;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    A:link {text-decoration: underline color: #FF6600;}
    A:visited {text-decoration: underline color: #FF6600;}
    A:active {text-decoration: underline color: #FF6600;}
    A:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: #FF6600;}
    </style>
    <a href="http://www.orange.es/livebox/apps">
        Here please download the Livebox Apps for your Smartphone
    </a>
</p>
<p>
    <a href="http://www.orange.es/livebox/apps">
        <img src="/images/QR_code.png">
    </a>
</p>
<script language="JavaScript">
init();
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is bruceforce an option?

Comment: I don't know, is it? @McMuffin

Comment: Is there a cooldown after etc. 3 login attempts? @LukeFuda

Comment: No @McMuffin, it is unlimited attempts

Comment: then you can use a bruteforce attack

Comment: I still there a script of some sort or a forum that you could give me to direct me in the right way. @McMuffin

Comment: I would love to have a Quantum Computer, then I could quite literally Brute Force absolutely anything. Unfortunately, Brute Force will take a long time and is a very inefficient method of hacking into a router. Sorry, bud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [link](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/popular-tools-for-brute-force-attacks/#gref) will help you understand how brute-force works and I hope it will guide you the right way

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (and I may be wrong), when you log into a router, it is like logging into a computer remotely.

That means you can automatically cross XSS, MySQL injection, and any other form of web hacking.  There may be a script that you can plug directly into the USB port of your router to effectively hack it or just brute force your way in.

I am not a hacker by any means so anything you read here is merely educated guesses.

Hope I helped.